# Apache2 Webserver issue

Tags: apache, apache2, http-status-code-404, virtualhost

I have a problem with my Apache2 server and I am hoping that you can help me out and fix this issue of mine!

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04 with Apache2 installed, and the problem I am having is that when I add a new website to my /var/www/ folder I cannot access it, it just gives me a 404 error saying that it does not exist

My first website is running great without any problems and that one is installed to /var/www/html.

Basically I want it to be as the following, when someone enters my domain [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) I want them to see the site I have in /var/www/html which they are currently doing.
But! When they enter [www.mydomain.com/phpbb](http://www.mydomain.com/phpbb) for example I want them to be directed to the second folder I created in the /var/www/ which is called phpbb for the moment.

I did try to fix this on my own, but I can't find any good explanations that I truly understand so is there anyone who can help me out with this?

This is how my virtualhost file is looking at the moment

```
<VirtualHost *:80>    
ServerAdmin kristofferforsberg@hotmail.com
ServerName myfirstsite.zapto.org
ServerAlias www.myfirstsite.zapto.org
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

And this is how I want my structure to be, and the message I am getting, let me know if there is anything else I need to show you guys.

Folder Structure picture:
[image: Folder Structure picture]

Error message:
[image: Error message]

Answer (score 0):

Why not move `phpbb/` into `/var/www/html`? No need for another VirtualHost, unless you use a different domain/port etc.

Comment: Thats my bad i should have mentioned it, but in the future i am going to have more domain names and subdomains thats why i want to make this work!

Comment: You may want to either set up those (sub-)domains as virtual hosts then (with the matching DocumentRoot), or look into [Aliases](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html) instead, if on the same host.

Comment: this is the part i don't understand i did read that, but could you possibly give me a code example of how my config should look like? if thats the only way to do it

Comment: There's a couple of examples on the page and also [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html#outside).

I don't have access to any apache2 setups right now, but it should be as simple as `Alias "/phpbb/" "/var/www/phpbb/"` (try with trailing slash first, you can always redirect /phpbb to /phpbb/ later.

Comment: But the thing is i got down how to add the domain and such, but my problem is i cant access the site locally if i put my phpbb in under the www folder, if i can get the access for me to work am sure i can figure out how to get it online, but the biggest issue is that i cant even access it now while its in /var/www/phpbb

Comment: well the DocumentRoot is /var/www/html, so as the "phpbb" directory is not within that, you cannot access it by design (by default).

Comment: But, i tried making another VirtualHost exactly the same as the ex i provided but i changed the DocumentRoot to phpbb, but i still cant access that? i still cant access it if i try to enter 192.168.5.58/phpbb

Comment: Well... that's not how virtual hosts work. You practically cannot have multiple hosts for the same servername/host+port combination - it will always use the first one that matches (possibly also using wildcards like `*:80`).